# Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'BehaviorSubject<string>'. in rxjs 6

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

On upgrade of rx js from 5 to 6, throws below error

[ts] Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'BehaviorSubject'.

**Current Behavior**

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

tokenSubject: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
return this.tokenSubject
                .filter(token => token != null)
                .take(1)
                .switchMap(token => {
                    return next.handle(this.addToken(req));
                });
```

[ts] Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'BehaviorSubject'.

**Environment**

```
 "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
   "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
```

Expected behavior

No error and working fine

**Previous Behavior**

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";
tokenSubject: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
return this.tokenSubject
                .filter(token => token != null)
                .take(1)
                .switchMap(token => {
                    return next.handle(this.addToken(req));
                });
```

[ts] Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'BehaviorSubject'.

**Environment**

```
"@angular/common": "^5.0.3",
  "rxjs": "^5.4.3"
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [RxJS v5.x to v6 Update Guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md)
 says:

> The previous coding style of chaining operators has been replaced by piping the result of one operator to another.

Use the piping syntax:

```
return this.tokenSubject.pipe(
    filter(token => token != null),
    take(1),
    switchMap(token => {
        return next.handle(this.addToken(req));
    })
);
```